# Name Error in Excel Uninitalized Contant in 'roo'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, excel, spreadsheet

I am trying to read an Excel file in Ruby On Rails.
I have done coding like this for reading the cell content from the Excel sheet.

```
def test
 require 'rubygems'
 require 'iconv'
 require 'roo'

 s = Excel.new("C:/Sites/hmmsapp/Book1.xls")
 s.default_sheet = s.sheets.first

 1.upto(4) do |line|
   roll = s.cell(line,'A')
   puts "#{roll} -------------"
 end
end
```

But on running this it always gives me this error.

```
NameError in HostelController#test

uninitialized constant HostelController::Excel
```

I have also included `iconv` as per suggestions for this problem. But there is no change in error.
Please give some light to removing this error & to read the excel file properly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try `Roo::Excel.new`

Or `Roo::Spreadsheet.new`